# How to detect Allow Contact button action in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

In my app, I retrieve phone contact lists and display its names in UITableView. As retrieving contact list, "Allow Contacts" popup is always displayed at first time as we all know. If I press "Allow" button, contact will not be displayed promptly. I need to go back and come again to this screen. Is there anyway that contacts will be displayed when press "Allow" button?

```
-(void)collectContacts {
    ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            if (granted) {
                ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBookRef);
                CFArrayRef allPeople = (ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBookRef, source, kABPersonSortByFirstName));
                CFIndex nPeople = CFArrayGetCount(allPeople);

                for (int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++) {

                    @autoreleasepool
                    {

                        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);

                        //get First Name
                        CFStringRef firstName = (CFStringRef)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
                        CFStringRef lastName = (CFStringRef)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
                        ABMultiValueRef multiPhones = ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonPhoneProperty);
                        CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiPhones, 0);
                        NSString *phoneNumber = (__bridge NSString *) phoneNumberRef;


                        CFDataRef imgData = ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
                        NSData *imageData = (__bridge NSData *)imgData;

                        NSString *firstname = [(__bridge NSString*)firstName copy];
                        NSString *lastname = [(__bridge NSString*)lastName copy];
                        if (!lastname || lastname == [NSNull null]) {
                            lastname = @"";
                        }

                        NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@", firstname, lastname, phoneNumber);

                        NSString *fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstname, lastname];

                        ContactObject *contactObj = [[ContactObject alloc] initWithUniqueId:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData] title:fullname phonenumber:phoneNumber];
                        [_objects addObject:contactObj];
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    } else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBookRef);
        CFArrayRef allPeople = (ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBookRef, source, kABPersonSortByFirstName));
        CFIndex nPeople = CFArrayGetCount(allPeople);

        for (int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++) {

            @autoreleasepool
            {

                ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);

                //get First Name
                CFStringRef firstName = (CFStringRef)ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
                CFStringRef lastName = (CFStringRef)ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonLastNameProperty);
                CFDataRef imgData = ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
                NSData *imageData = (__bridge NSData *)imgData;
                ABMultiValueRef multiPhones = ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonPhoneProperty);
                CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiPhones, 0);
                NSString *phoneNumber = (__bridge NSString *) phoneNumberRef;

                NSString *firstname = [(__bridge NSString*)firstName copy];
                NSString *lastname = [(__bridge NSString*)lastName copy];

                if (!lastname || lastname == [NSNull null]) {
                    lastname = @"";
                }

                NSString *fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstname, lastname];

                ContactObject *contactObj = [[ContactObject alloc] initWithUniqueId:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData] title:fullname phonenumber:phoneNumber];
                [_objects addObject:contactObj];
              }
        }
    }

    [_contactTable reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to handle this is to use:

```
void ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(ABAddressBookRef addressBook, ABAddressBookRequestAccessCompletionHandler completion);
```

There is not much you can do until you have been granted access. You simply have to wait until your completion handler is called. At THAT time (depending) on if you were granted access you can populate your table, not before.

You can check your access rights at any point before or after using:

```
ABAuthorizationStatus ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus(void);
```

From the Apple docs:

> Discussion
>
> Use this function to request access to address book data. This call will not block while the user is being asked for access, allowing your app to continue running. Until access has been granted, any address book references your app has will not contain any data, and any attempt to modify data will fail with an error type of kABOperationNotPermittedByUserError. The user is only asked for permission the first time you request access. Later calls use the permission granted by the user.
>
> The completion handler is called on an arbitrary queue. If your app uses an address book throughout the app, you are responsible for ensuring that all usage of that address book is dispatched to a single queue to ensure correct thread-safe operation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the permission alert programatically and once it is allowed then you need to fetch contacts and load in UITableView:

```
ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, nil), ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (!granted){
                    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Contacts Access Denied"
                                                message:@"This app requires access to your device's Contacts.\n\nPlease enable Contacts access for this app in Settings / Privacy / Contacts"
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
            } else {
                //access authorized, fetch and display
            }
        });
    });
```